# Parse JSON Array and load into hive table

Tags: json, hive

I have a Json Array like as below

```
[{"Name":"xxxx","Machine":"Machine1"},{"Name":"yyyy","Machine":"Machine2"},{"Name":"zzzz","Machine":"Machine3"}]
```

I need to parse that data and load into a hive table like below

```
Name    Machine

xxxx    Machine1
yyyy    Machine2
zzzz    Machine3
```

could someone please help?

Comment: I have done using regex_replace, split and explode.                       
 select explode(b.arr) as output from
(select split(a.new,';') as arr from
(select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(jsonarray.json,"\\}\\,\\{","\\}\\;\\{"),"\\[|\\]","") as new FROM jsonarray)as a)as b                                             is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select  j.Name,j.Machine

from    jsonarray t
        lateral view explode(split(substr(t.json,2),'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)')) e
        lateral view json_tuple(e.col,'Name','Machine') j as Name,Machine
;
```

---

```
+------+----------+
| name | machine  |
+------+----------+
| xxxx | Machine1 |
| yyyy | Machine2 |
| zzzz | Machine3 |
+------+----------+
```