# In Hive, how does this pattern recognize nested json from json arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, hive, hiveql

I am reading this question: [Parse JSON Array and load into hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450251/parse-json-array-and-load-into-hive-table).

The nested json comprises multiple `}` and `{`, but the regex pattern `(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)` can recognize json elements. Could anyone please explain how this split function works?

```
select 
split(substr('[{"a":{"c":"sss"},"w":123},{"b":2},{"r":{"c":"sss"},"w":555}]',2),'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)')[0],
split(substr('[{"a":{"c":"sss"},"w":123},{"b":2},{"r":{"c":"sss"},"w":555}]',2),'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)')[1],
split(substr('[{"a":{"c":"sss"},"w":123},{"b":2},{"r":{"c":"sss"},"w":555}]',2),'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)')[2]
```

and the result is:

```
{"a":{"c":"sss"},"w":123}   {"b":2}    {"r":{"c":"sss"},"w":555}]
```

Btw, an array without `[` is sent to `json_tuple`, like `{"a":1},{"b":2}]`. This is not a json array at all and why `json_tuple` can work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEXP `'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)'` matching comma only between } and {, not including curly brackets

`(?<=\\})` is a zero-width lookbehind, asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is }

`(?=\\{)` is a zero-width positive lookahead assertion, means it should be { after current position

So, split function splits string to array using comma between }{, not including brackets. This results in array of  these elements:

element 0 is `{"a":{"c":"sss"},"w":123}`
element 1 is `{"b":2}`
element 2 is `{"r":{"c":"sss"},"w":555}]`

in the mentioned answer, `explode` is applied to array, it produces rows with array elements.

`json_tuple` receives element (array already exploded), not array. Yes, it is extra `]` in last element, better remove it also, json_tuple recognizes element as struct, not as array, because there is no `[`.