# Can we flatten column which contain Json as value in Hive table?

Tags: sql, json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have one hive column 'events' with Json values.How can i flatten this Json to create one hive table with columns as the key field of Json.Is it even possible?
ex- I need hive table columns to be events,start_date,id,details with corresponding values.

| events |

|[{"start_date":20201230,"id":"3245ret","details":"Imp"},{"start_date":20201228,"id":"3245rtr","details":"NoImp"}] |

|[{"start_date":20191230,"id":"3245ret","details":"vImp"},{"start_date":20191228,"id":"3245rwer","details":"NoImp"}]|

Comment: what value do you want to  keep for events column

Comment: for event column, values will be same what it is, but the values for start_date,id and details column should be same as the values in the Json

Comment: in a single row there is two json object i.e, array of two json object. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes,it can be more as well

Comment: Thanks a lot @leftjoin, it solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

```
select events, 
get_json_object(element,'$.id') as id,
get_json_object(element,'$.start_date') as start_date,
get_json_object(element,'$.details') as details
from
(
select '[{"start_date":20201230,"id":"3245ret","details":"Imp"},{"start_date":20201228,"id":"3245rtr","details":"NoImp"}]' as events
union all 
select '[{"start_date":20191230,"id":"3245ret","details":"vImp"},{"start_date":20191228,"id":"3245rwer","details":"NoImp"}]' as events
) s lateral view outer explode (split(regexp_replace(events, '\\[|\\]',''),'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)')) e as element
```

Initial string is splitted by comma between curly brackets, ([see explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640378/2700344)), array exploded with lateral view and JSON objects parsed using `get_json_object`

Result:

```
 events                                                                                                             id       start_date details
[{"start_date":20201230,"id":"3245ret","details":"Imp"},{"start_date":20201228,"id":"3245rtr","details":"NoImp"}]   3245ret  20201230  Imp
[{"start_date":20201230,"id":"3245ret","details":"Imp"},{"start_date":20201228,"id":"3245rtr","details":"NoImp"}]   3245rtr  20201228  NoImp
[{"start_date":20191230,"id":"3245ret","details":"vImp"},{"start_date":20191228,"id":"3245rwer","details":"NoImp"}] 3245ret  20191230  vImp
[{"start_date":20191230,"id":"3245ret","details":"vImp"},{"start_date":20191228,"id":"3245rwer","details":"NoImp"}] 3245rwer 20191228  NoImp
```